# Socket.io "reference error: io is not defined"

Tags: node.js, express, sockets, websocket, socket.io

I am trying to use socket in my app, but it gives me the error
[image]

The weird thing is, I created a test app to test socket with the same code I use in this app, and it worked perfectly. But on this app something doesn't quite work. I believe it has something to do with that I have multiple different html pages so I have to specify the path, but my attempts at doing that have all failed.

Here is the current code that works on test app but gives io is not defined error.

in html:
[image]

In node.js:

```
import http from 'http';
import { Server } from "socket.io";
const server = http.createServer(app);
const io = new Server(server);

io.on('connection', (socket) => {
  console.log('a user connected');
  socket.on('/chatmessage', (stuff) => {
    var currentUser = stuff.currentUser;
    db.collection('Messaging').where('Users',  'array-contains', currentUser).onSnapshot((querySnap) => {
      console.log('REALTIME CALLED')
      const doc = querySnap.docChanges()[0].doc;
        const data = querySnap.docChanges()[0].doc.data();
      var theObj = {id: doc.id, User1: data.User1, User2: data.User2, Users: data.Users, Last: data.Last, Created: data.Created, User1Messages: data.User1Messages, User2Messages: data.User2Messages }
      socket.emit('/chatmessagechange', dataToSend);

    }).catch((err) => {
      console.log(err);
      var dataToSend = {Error:"yes"};
      socket.emit('chat message change', dataToSend);
    })  
  })
});
```

"A user connected" never logs, because of the client side error I get when the page is ran.
If the error is indeed something related to paths, as I have multiple different html files, how would I appropriately configure this?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, socket.io does not have any interface var server, if you are trying to use socket in front I think for the front end you need to use socket.io-client.
Refer to [this](https://www.valentinog.com/blog/socket-react/) as a reference.

```
import http from "http";
const socketIO=require("socket.io"); // need to change like this
const server = http.createServer(app);
const io = socketIO(server); // need to change like this

io.on("connection", (socket) => {
  console.log("a user connected");
  socket.on("/chatmessage", (stuff) => {
    var currentUser = stuff.currentUser;
    db.collection("Messaging")
      .where("Users", "array-contains", currentUser)
      .onSnapshot((querySnap) => {
        console.log("REALTIME CALLED");
        const doc = querySnap.docChanges()[0].doc;
        const data = querySnap.docChanges()[0].doc.data();
        var theObj = {
          id: doc.id,
          User1: data.User1,
          User2: data.User2,
          Users: data.Users,
          Last: data.Last,
          Created: data.Created,
          User1Messages: data.User1Messages,
          User2Messages: data.User2Messages,
        };
        socket.emit("/chatmessagechange", dataToSend);
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        console.log(err);
        var dataToSend = { Error: "yes" };
        socket.emit("chat message change", dataToSend);
      });
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I used the socket script at the top of the head tag

```
<head>
    <script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
    <script>
          var socket = io()
    </script>
</head>
```

socket. io-client is an npm module, if you are using react in the front end, you can use it otherwise you have to add the above lines in the HTML header

Please refer in case of any reference: https://socket.io/docs/v3/client-api/

Thanks